# AS3 Warning: Class 'Main' does not extend the 'DefineBits' asset base class 'flash.display.Bitmap or flash.display.BitmapData'

Tags: actionscript-3, error-handling, flashdevelop

I'm trying to add a simple background image but when i place the embed code for the image i get this error:

Warning: Class 'Main' does not extend the 'DefineBits' asset base class 'flash.display.Bitmap or flash.display.BitmapData'.

EDIT: now i'm not getting this error but the background image doesnt display still

Here's my code:

```
package 
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.events.Event;

/**
 * ...
 * @author Callum Singh
 */
[Embed(source="../assets/BackGround.png")]
public class Main extends Sprite 
{
    public var chicken:Hero

    public function Main():void 
    {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        chicken = new Hero();
        stage.addChild(chicken);
    }

}

}
```

Any Help or Guidance with this would be appreciated.

Thankyou in Advance.

Comment: i think this is a bug that has been fixed for some time, are you using the newest sdk?

Comment: I am not sure. would it be possible for you to the ink the latest sdk to me? thanks

Comment: you can check it in flash develop at project > properties > sdk , i think 4.6 is the newest http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html

Comment: You can't embed asset out of the class, they have to be inside the class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

This warning actually does not let instantiating the class. The class name exists, but if try to instantiate it always returns null. I got the same warning and was able to solve it as follows :

Please modify this line :

```
[Embed(source="../assets/BackGround.png")]
```

to this :

```
[Embed(source="../assets/BackGround.png", mimeType = "image/png")]
```

It solved the problem at my end.